# Display specific section of a report using bookmark

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having trouble creating bookmark for one of my reports. The outline of report is like this:

**MainTitleField**

**SecondTitleField                    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec**

```
                        Total
```

MaintTitleField has 4 records: MT1,Mt2,MT3,MT4

SecondTitleField has 5 records, ST1,ST2,ST3,ST4,ST5

So the whole report looks like this:

**M1                Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec**

**ST1**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST2**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST3**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST4**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST5**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

```
                  **Total**
```

**M2        Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec**

**ST1**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST2**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST3**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST4**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST5**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

```
     **Total**
```

**M3   Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec**

**ST1**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST2**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST3**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST4**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST5**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

```
     **Total**
```

**M4       Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec**

**ST1**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST2**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST3**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST4**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST5**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

```
    **Total**
```

Now I would like to add a bookmark in MainTitleField such that if I hover my mouse over MT1 and click on it, it will only display

**MT1               Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec**

**ST1**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST2**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST3**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST4**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

**ST5**               Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val Val  Val  Val Val  Val   Val

```
                        **Total**
```

Please note that the data in (ST1,ST2,ST3,ST4,ST5) are specific to each of the Main Title so depending on the main titles selected, the data in the Second Titles will be different. So far, I have been unsuccessful as whenever I click on the bookmark, it shows the entire report so the bookmark is not working as I would like.

I have tried looking up at examples of bookmarks online, however, there are no similar examples and most of them are fairly simple. Please let me know if you have any idea on this matter. Any feedback will greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Well I go to the MainTitle Textbox<Action<GoToBookMark<1. 
Then I select the rows SecondTitle and Total<Properties<Bookmark=1. I know this is where I'm messing up because it displays the entire report and not the specific section

Comment: A bookmark is just a specific point in the report. You will always see the whole report. If you only want to see specific data then I would siggest you use a linked report so when you click on the cell it runs the report with parameters to select only the data you want.